# Copying data from HDFS to hive using SQOOP

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I want to copy data from `HDFS` to `hive` table. I tried below code but it doesn't throw any error and data is also not copied in mentioned hive table. Below is my code:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sampleOne \
--username root \
--password root \
--external-table-dir "/WithFields" \
--hive-import \
--hive-table "sampleone.customers"
```

where `sampleone` is database in hive and `customers` is newly created table in hive and `--external-table-dir` is the HDFS path from where I want to load data in hive table. What else I am missing in this above code ??

Comment: You do not need Sqoop to copy data from HDFS to Hive. Just create Hive table with your HDFS location or copy data to existing Hive table location using `hadoop  fs -scp` command

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If data is in `HDFS`, you do not need `Sqoop` to populate a `Hive` table. Steps to do this are below:

**This is the data in HDFS**

```
# hadoop fs -ls /example_hive/country
/example_hive/country/country1.csv

# hadoop fs -cat /example_hive/country/*
1,USA
2,Canada
3,USA
4,Brazil
5,Brazil
6,USA
7,Canada
```

**This is the Hive table creation DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE sampleone.customers
(
  id int, 
  country string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

**Verify Hive table is empty**

```
hive (sampleone)> select * from sampleone.customers;
<no rows>
```

**Load Hive table**

```
hive (sampleone)> LOAD DATA INPATH '/example_hive/country' INTO TABLE sampleone.customers;
```

**Verify Hive table has data**

```
hive (sampleone)> select * from sampleone.customers;
1   USA
2   Canada
3   USA
4   Brazil
5   Brazil
6   USA
7   Canada
```

**Note**: This approach will move data from `/example_hive/country` location on `HDFS` to `Hive` warehouse directory (which will again be on `HDFS`) backing the table.

Comment: yeah I am aware of this . I thought is there any way via sqoop to transfer data that's why I tried . Anyways, thanks.

Comment: @Debugger Sqoop is not used between HDFS and Hive. It's used between a JDBC database such as Mysql and HDFS, optionally creating or exporting a Hive table.

Comment: @Jagrut You could also skip the load step and just make an external table over the folder with the data file

Comment: @cricket_007 Correct, that is another way - An external Hive table could be created pointing to the existing HDFS directory. The question suggested that the Hive table sampleone.customers was already available. Hence, I suggested the approach of running a command to just populate it.